# Where can I find the basic definitions used by researchers in string processing / matching / searching.

Tags: computer-science

[Fast String Correction with Levenshtein-Automata](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.16.652)

This paper uses the terms *descendent* and *stroke*, and I can't find definitions for them by googling.  Could you recommend a book, or page.

Grazie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don’t know whether this terminology is standard, so I can’t give you a reference, but I can explain how it’s used in the paper. I think that the easiest way to explain is by an example.

Consider the words $u=$ `abcde` and $v=$ `aebbfg`; the Levenshtein distance between them is $5$, as illustrated by this sequence of edit operations:

```
   abcde  
   abde                              delete c
   abbe                              substitute b for d
   aebbe                             insert e
   aebbf                             substitute f for e  
   aebbfg                            insert g
```

(Other sequences of length $5$ are possible.) The letters of $v$ are of three types.

1. Those that were in $u$ and were never changed: these are the `a` and the first `b`. These letters are the descendants of the `a` and `b` in $u$, respectively. (In the paper these letters are the ones ‘not touched by any edit operation’ in the discussion immediately following Lemma 2.0.2.)
2. Those that are the result of substituting a letter for a letter in $u$: these are the second `b` and the `f`. These letters are the descendants of the `d` and `e` in $u$, respectively.
3. Those that were inserted: these are the `e` and the `g`. These are not descendants of any letter of $u$.

Note also that the `c` of $u$ has no descendant in $v$, because it was deleted.

Now construct a bipartite graph $G(u,v)$. Its vertices are the letters of $u$ as one of the parts and the letters of $v$ as the other part. Connect a letter $x$ in $u$ to a letter $y$ in $v$ if and only if $y$ is the descendant of $x$. $G(u,v)$ is the paper’s *trace representation*, and a *stroke* in the paper’s terminology is simply one of these edges. In my example the picture looks like this:

```
                a e b b f g  
                |  /  | |
                a b c d e
```

(I put $u$ on the bottom and $v$ on the top in order to follow the convention used in Figure 2.1 of the paper.) $G(u,v)$ has four edges; in the paper’s terminology, this trace representation has four strokes. As noted in the discussion immediately following Lemma 2.0.2, no strokes cross, each letter of $u$ that has no attached edge was deleted, and each letter of $v$ that has no attached edge was inserted.

Comment: Great explanation.  Thank you.
 (>'-')> <('-'<) ^('-')^ v('-')v <('-'<) (>'-')> ^(^-^)>